# Efficient data structure for finding constrained shortest path in a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, struct, graph-algorithm

The constrained shortest path problem in a graph `G=(V,E)` is, given source node `s` and sink node `t`, find the shortest path from `s` to `t` such that the total resource consumed on the path is at most scalar `R`. Each arc `(i,j)` in the graph has a cost, scalar `c_{ij}` and uses up the resource to the tune of scalar `r_{ij}`. The cost of the path is the sum of costs of individual arcs constituting the path and the resource consumed by the path is the sum of resource of individual arcs constituting the path. This problem is known to be `NP-HARD`.

Most implementations to solve this problem use a dynamic programming approach which essentially does a sort of brute force enumeration along with other clever fathoming approaches to reduce the amount of searching done.

Dynamic programming is implemented using a [labelling approach](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Stefan_Irnich2/publication/227142556_Shortest_Path_Problems_with_Resource_Constraints/links/0deec523898ae43b84000000.pdf).

I have implemented this algorithm using a couple of different approaches and I want to ensure if I am doing it as efficiently as possible.

The labelling approach creates multiple labels, which are essentially partial paths from `s` to various other nodes. A large number of labels are created during the algorithm (note, the problem is `NP HARD`) until a stopping criterion is met.

Each label can be represented as a `struct` as follows.

```
struct labels_s {
    double current_states[10];
    double unscanned_states[10];
    int already_visited[100];//If node i is already visited on partial path, already_visited[i] = 1, else 0
    int do_not_visit[100];//if node i is not to be visited from this label, do_not_visit[i] = 1; 0 otherwise
    struct labels_s* prev;
    struct labels_s* next;
};
```

As the algorithm proceeds, many of the above structs need to be created and stored.

**Method 1:**

A very early implementation I had of this was very computationally inefficient. This involved `new`ing structs as and when new labels were required and explicitly maintaining these in a linked list using the members `next` and `prev` of the `struct`s.

**Method 2:**

Instead of `new`ing `structs`, I started storing the new structs in a `std::vector` container:

`vector <labels_s> labels;`

To do this, and since `vector` gives integer index access to various labels, `prev` and `next` of `struct labels_s` could be changed to `int prev;` and `int next;`

Storing a label involved the following:

```
struct labels_s newlabel;//Step 1
//populate newlabel's members//Step 2
labels.push_back(newlabel);//Step 3
```

Computational times on the same problem using **Method 2** are significantly better than **Method 1**. Labels are only added at the end of the vector. There is no need to insert in the middle of the vector or delete from the vector.

Is there any other way of managing these labels apart from **Method 2**?

My concern primarily is with Step 3 of **Method 2**. Since `push_back()` creates a copy of `newlabel`, is this copy operation costly and can this be avoided?

One alternative I was considering was to maintain a vector of pointers to label structs instead of vector of label structs as I do currently. But it appears to me that maintaining a vector of pointers to label structs should be no more efficient than **Method 1**.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Your "constrained shortest path" sounds like "first, for each vertex weight, do: if(weight>max) then weight=max. Then, make a normal shortest path search". ... Given that, it might help to search solutions for normal shortest path problems. And while I don't have all details for Dijkstra in my head currently, I'm pretty sure a dynamically shrinking/growing vector is not necessary.

Comment: Normally, A* only stores a pointer to the immediate previous node.

Comment: And you don't have to worry about loops because of the (global) open-set and closed-set, and you only ever advance from the shortest node.

Comment: Could you just store pointers in the vector? - no copy then.

Comment: @noelicus I think it is likely to be less efficient than Method 2 and possibly as inefficient as Method 1.

Comment: I would be surprised - but then you don't specify why each method is slow. Have you tried profiling it? It would save the guesswork.

Comment: since you're done with choosing an algorithm and have an implementation, now the first (iterative) step you should do is to better understand where most of time is spent. Do profiling, I'd start with a sampling profiler. Otherwise you can waste lots of time improving non important places, and making your code much more complicated than required

Comment: @noelicus Storing pointers instead of the objects themselves is very cache unfriendly, so I wouldn't be surprised if it is in fact less efficient then just doing the copying. However, I agree that profiling is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 you can use `emplace_back` ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)) to construct a label in place at the end of the vector. You could do:

```
labels.emplace_back();  // default construct a new label at the end of labels
// then populate members like this:
labels.back().member1 = val1;
```

Depending on your use case, you could also create a constructor for `labels_s` that takes all the values of the members and initializes them. In this case you could write

```
labels.emplace_back(val1, val2, …);
```

and be done.

Apart from this, you should `reserve` ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)) generously before populating `labels` to avoid frequent reallocations.

Comment: That may be exactly what I am looking for. So, with your suggestion, Steps (1 and 2) and Step 3 are essentially done only once yes? With my current implementation, Step 3 was essentially a repetition of Step 1 and 2. With emplace_back(); I could then just have labels[labels.size()-1].member1 = xyz; and so on?

Comment: Step 3 (the copying of the temporary variable) doesn't happen, you're directly populating the label in the vector, no copying necessary.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the edit. Yes, you can do exactly that. labels.back().member1 = xyz would probably be cleaner, though. Edited to make this clearer.